# How to analyze the following non-linear ODE asymptotically,

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, asymptotics

### $y\frac{\text{d}^2y}{\text{d}x^2}-2\left(\frac{\text{d}y}{\text{d}x}\right)^2+xy^3\frac{\text{d}y}{\text{d}x}=0.$

I want to analyze the above non-linear ODE asymptotically. Do you have an idea?

Comment: Which asymptote? $x\rightarrow \pm \infty$? $xy^3  \frac{\operatorname{d} y }{\operatorname{d}x} \ll 1$? $\left(\frac{\operatorname{d} y }{\operatorname{d}x}\right)^2 \gg y\frac{\operatorname{d}^2 y }{\operatorname{d}x^2}$? I don't know which, if any of the asymptotes I mentioned are valid, but I am sure that more than one asymptote exists.

Comment: Yes $x \rightarrow \infty$, how to analyze it